# STRANGE behavior of css with react.js

Tags: javascript, css, web, reactjs

I'm facing REALLY strange(to me) behavior of my web app.
Model of app is:

```
|-TaskBox
  \
   |-TaskList
     \
      |-TaskElement
      |-TaskElement
  \
   |-AddNewTask
```

And i get strange white gaps under each TaskElement like on the pic:

[image: gaps]

The code for task elements rendering in react is:

```
return (
    <div className="taskElement" style={this.state.style}>
        <div className="textArea">
            <p>{this.state.text}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="iconsArea">
            <i className="material-icons" onClick={this.toEditMode}>mode_edit</i>
            <i className="material-icons" onClick={this.Delete}>delete</i>
            <i className="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
            <i className="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
        </div> 
     </div>
);
```

I don't know why this gaps happen but when i add any plaintext symbol to xml render code gaps DISAPPEAR. What the hell is happening there?

ex of gaps disappear:
[image: no gaps]

and the . added to code here:
   return (

```
<div className="taskElement" style={this.state.style}>
            <div className="textArea">
                <p>{this.state.text}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="iconsArea">
                <i className="material-icons" onClick={this.toEditMode}>mode_edit</i>
                <i className="material-icons" onClick={this.Delete}>delete</i>
                <i className="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
                <i className="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
       </div> .  (this is the dot i added)
       </div>
    );
```

Comment: Mind sharing your styles? :)

Comment: @MichelleTilley which ones do you want? All code is at https://github.com/feijihn/todolist_react and you can also go to 84.23.33.186:3000 if you want some firebug exploring

Comment: Please help us with the styles for the classes in your html sample, so we don't need to scan through all your css.

Comment: inspect the whitespace using your browser's development tools and figure out who's adding extra margins or padding.

Comment: @DanO I can't find any extra paddings or margins. You can try yourself at
84.23.33.186:3000
To LGSon: Everything in the repo https://github.com/feijihn/todolist_react inside public/css folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `taskElement` is `inline-block` so adding `vertical-align: top` to it should do the trick.

Comment: It did! I would appreciate any explanation to this situation because i still don't understand the origin of these gaps

Comment: This article describes it very well: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/